# PHP - Make 'new' of a Class and Arguments set in a string

Tags: php, class, variables

I've a Class and Arguments set in a variable like this:

```
$myVar = '\Api\MyClass(\DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED)';
```

I need to make a `new` of this variable.

I tried multiple solutions and at the end the `new` of the Class was solved but I cannot pass the argument.

My code is:

```
<?php

$myVar = '\Api\MyClass(\DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED)';
$className = substr($myVar, 0, strpos($myVar, "(")); // $className will be: \Api\MyClass
if (class_exists($className)) {
    preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/', $myVar, $classArguments); $classArguments will be: \DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED
    $obj = new $className($classArguments[1]); // it doesn't work
}
```

the problem is that `$classArguments[1]` is passed as `string` to my class. Below the difference:

```
// It works
$p = \DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED;
var_dump($p);

// and return
string(15) "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP"
```

```
// It doesn't work
$p = "\DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED";
var_dump($p);

// return
string(36) "\DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED"
```

can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask your use case? I can’t think of any valid use case where you may end up with this kind of string.

Answer (score 0):

New can only be used to create an instance. Make your constructor expecting that date format as default, so you are not required to pass it.

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct(string $dateFormat = DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED)
    {
    }
}

$var = 'MyClass';

$instance = new $var;
```

```
$p = "\DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED";
```

will not work, because that is now a string and not the constants value.

You also can pass something like so

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct(string $something = '')
    {
        echo $something;
    }
}

$var = 'MyClass';
$text = 'Hello world';
$instance = new $var($text);
```

> Hello world

If you need the complete string to be parsed try `eval()`, *but not recommended*.

```
$var = 'new MyClass("hello world");';
$instance = eval($var);
```

> Hello world

or, *but not recommended*.

```
$var = 'MyClass("hello world")';
$instance = eval("new {$var};");
```

> Hello world

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `constant` function to get the value of a constant.

A simple example class that just outputs the parameter value when initialized.

```
class MyClass
{
    function __construct($arg) {
        echo "$arg\n";
    }
}

new MyClass('anything'); // outputs "anything"
```

This is just a helper that gets the class name and argument string from a string like your `$myVar`.

```
function parseClassAndArgument(string $str): array {
    preg_match('/(.*)\((.*)\)/', $str, $matches);
    [, $className, $argument] = $matches;
    return [$className, $argument];
}
```

This helper allows you to pass either a string value or a name of a constant, and guesses which one it is based on whether there is a `::` in the string name. You can replace this with just the `constant($argument)` part if you know `$myVar` will always contain a constant name.

```
function parseArgValue(string $argument): string {
    return strpos($argument, '::') ? constant($argument) : $argument;
}
```

This recognizes that `$argument` refers to a constant and outputs `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP`

```
$myVar = 'MyClass(\DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED)';
[$className, $argument] = parseClassAndArgument($myVar);
new $className(parseArgValue($argument));
```

This outputs the string `foo` as is.

```
$myVar = 'MyClass(foo)';
[$className, $argument] = parseClassAndArgument($myVar);
new $className(parseArgValue($argument));
```

This is a simplified example that only handles one parameter for the class constructor, but I hope it helps to get you along!

Comment: You could of course include the argument string parsing inside the class constructor; no need to do it outside the class.